# cardiac, cardiologic, cardiological?

Tags: adjectives

What's the right adjective from "cardiology"?

"Cardiac" seems to refer to the heart itself more than to the science of cardiology. There's "cardiological" in Collins dictionary, and both "cardiologic" and "cardiological" at dictionary.com. I've searched the Internet and come across all the three above in similar contexts, so I'm a bit confused now. I've also noticed that the noun "cardiology" itself is often used as an adjective. The context I'm interested in is:

*At the conference, the physicians agreed that a **cardiology/cardiac/cardiologic/cardiological** section of the association should be established.*

Thx in advance!

Comment: As you say, the word _cardiologic_ seems to exist, but I think _cardiological_ is more usual.

Comment: Actually, "cardiology" seems to be most common in the context I need: "the Geriatric Cardiology Section of the Spanish Society of Cardiology", "the Sports Cardiology section of the American College of Cardiology" etc. (???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to modify? Cardiological is what Merriam-Webster recommends, but it's not very commonly used. The prefix cardio- is more frequent.

Common usage in medicine would be cardiology section.

Comment: Well, my question goes down to the example above. Which of the four is the most appropriate in that particular context?